# TPM 2.0 device which supports Linux kernel via TCG_TIS or TCG_TIS_SPI

Tags: linux, drivers, tpm

How to find out if TPM device supports `"TPM 2.0 FIFO Interface"` ([`TCG_TIS`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/char/tpm/Kconfig#n47)) and `"TPM 2.0 FIFO Interface - (SPI)"` ([`TCG_TIS_SPI`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/char/tpm/Kconfig#n58)), when they don't specify it?

I'm particularly interested in [TPM SLB 9665 Xenonboard](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/evaluation-boards/tpm-65-xenonboard/), as it has JTPM1, which is on my board ([Supermicro H11SSL-i board](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/EPYC7000/MNL-2085.pdf), which recommends [Infineon AOM-TPM-9665](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/TPM.pdf), which is actually [TPM SLB 9665 Xenonboard](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/evaluation-boards/tpm-65-xenonboard/).

Comment: Note, question originally asked https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232654/tpm-2-0-device-which-supports-linux-and-has-jtpm1, here I put it differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your third link you can get [this PDF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-OPTIGA_TPM-PB-v10_15-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46145da30e80145efa2f0b96a8e) in which a product summary table specifies that only products with a sales code starting with "SLB 9670" will use the SPI interface. As you are talking about SLB 9665, that excludes `TCG_TIS_SPI`.

On my system, I have an Asus-branded Infineon SLB 9665 TPM which works fine with the `TCG_TIS` driver in Linux.

Note that there seems to be two possible LPC connector types: a 20-pin connector with pin 4 removed (known as 20-1), and a 14-pin connector with smaller pins and a finer pitch, known as 14-1.

According to [the manual of your motherboard](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/EPYC7000/MNL-2085.pdf) (as mentioned in your previous question in the Security SE), you would need one with the 20-1 style connector. And the page you linked with the specifications of the TPM SLB 9665 Xenonboard explicitly says it has the 20-pin connector, so both physical and driver compatibility seem to be covered.

Comment: Thanks a lot! + I put links to pdf to this question.